# Which type of scale is it? Likert type or Likert scale?

Tags: survey, likert

I have a basic question regarding the type of question. Are these likert type or likert scale? What makes the difference between these two?

The questions are like this with the following options

Strongly Agree
Agree
Neutral
Disagree
Strongly Disagree

1. Do you think Automated system will help you?
2. Do you think there is need for camera on this road?
3. Do you think the intelligent parking system will help you?